# Display JSON object's contents returned from an URL on an html page

Tags: json, jquery

I have JSON object returned from an URL in the format

```
<pre>
    [{"merchant":"eletspay","accountName":"hello","accountType":"Savings","ifscCode":"5545","email":"mypal.1989@gmail.com","phoneNum":"98654567876","isDefaultAccount":false},{"merchant":"eletspay","accountName":"helloi32irn","accountType":"Savings","ifscCode":"5545","email":"mypal.appa99721989@gmail.com","phoneNum":"98654567876","isDefaultAccount":false}]
    </pre>
```

And I want to loop through the JSON object for each index to display all of the contents in an html table where the table is

```
<pre>
<table class= "dataTable">
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="activate"></td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[1.value]</td>

                    </tr>
<tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="activate"</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                    <td>jsonObject[2.value]</td>
                                            </tr>
</table>
</pre>
```

Where `jsonObject[1.value]` will be the data at index 1 and `jsonObject[2.value]` will be the data at index 2 and so on.

PS: I'm new to Javascript and hence Jquery, so please ingore/rectify any stupid errors in the html part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aBZDg/13/:

```
var jsonData = [{"merchant":"eletspay","accountName":"hello","accountType":"Savings","ifscCode":"5545","email":"mypal.1989@gmail.com","phoneNum":"98654567876","isDefaultAccount":false},{"merchant":"eletspay","accountName":"helloi32irn","accountType":"Savings","ifscCode":"5545","email":"mypal.appa99721989@gmail.com","phoneNum":"98654567876","isDefaultAccount":false}];

function writeTable() {
    var out = '';

    for(var row=0; row<jsonData.length; row++) {
        out += '<tr>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].merchant + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].accountName + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].accountType + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].ifscCode + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].email + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].phoneNum + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + jsonData[row].isDefaultAccount + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
    }

    document.write(out);
}​
```

and then call this function where you want to show table.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Merchant</th>
        <th>AccountName</th>
        <th>AccountType</th>
        <th>IfscCode</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>PhoneNum</th>
        <th>IsDefaultAccount</th>
    </tr>
    <script>writeTable();</script>
</table>
```

Comment: This does print but i have new problem. I already had a table with headers (<th>) in it and this looping printed in an un-ordered way. Can you please help me out with printing the header along with these rows? The header will have the text to show what the column is.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle.net link?

Comment: I have changed the answer as per your requirements. Please check it.

Comment: I will check if it works. I anyway uploaded the screenshot of the table i need. Please check the image @ - http://i.imgur.com/DtIeU.png - of the table that want to create.

Comment: Hey Mali!! I didn't use your writeTable(); but i managed to print the table with all the rows using your other code. The problem was that I was coding ::: out += +'<tr>' instead of 
::: out += +'<tr>'. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquerytemplate

http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2011/3/1/using-jquery-templates-to-bind-to-json-data.aspx

This will loop the json data returned from your url

Comment: Ya, but as I'm just starting on Jquery, I don't want to use plugins. I want to get a hang of it.